# How to disable cursor blinking in Kile, TeXworks and/or Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, texworks, kile

I disabled cursor blinking in my operating system (Ubuntu 16.04), but this did not influence the cursor behaviour in these editors. Does anyone know how to stop cursor blinking in these programmes?